# Android - как заменить фрагмент при нажатии эл. в BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android

Как передать значение и обновить фрагмент? Хотел решить это обычной заменой, но тут тоже проблема. Делаю так, но выдает ошибку:

```
public class BottomSheetDialogView {

        static final String[] sStringList = new String[] {
                "dru", "mto", "3", "4"};

        public BottomSheetDialogView(Context context) {
            BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.numb_dialog, null);


            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager((context), 1));

            recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter());

            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.show();        
        }


        public static void show(Context context) {
            new BottomSheetDialogView(context);
        }


        private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private String mBoundString;
            private TextView mTextView;
            private  View mView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mView = itemView;
                mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numb);
            }
        }


        private static class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {


            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numb_item, null);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }


            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.mTextView.setText(sStringList[position]);
                holder.mBoundString = sStringList[position];


                holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Context context = view.getContext();
                        SettingsFragment news = new SettingsFragment();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((StartActivity)context).getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,  news).commit();
                    }
                });
            }


            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return sStringList.length;

            }        
      }

}
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
Process: ru.667.566, PID: 14174                                                                  
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to ru.667.566.StartActivity
at ru.amon.hellonhmt.Dialog.NumbSheetDialogView$SimpleAdapter$1.onClick(NumbSheetDialogView.java:146)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4626)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19293)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:136)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Обновляете код так:

```
public class BottomSheetDialogView {

    static final String[] sStringList = new String[] {
            "dru", "mto", "3", "4"};

    private View.OnClickListener clickListener;

    public BottomSheetDialogView(Context context, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.numb_dialog, null);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager((context), 1));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter());



        dialog.setContentView(view);
        dialog.show();

    }


    public static void show(Context context) {
        new BottomSheetDialogView(context);
    }


    private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private String mBoundString;
        private TextView mTextView;
        private  View mView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numb);
        }
    }


    private static class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numb_item, null);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mTextView.setText(sStringList[position]);
            holder.mBoundString = sStringList[position];

            holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return sStringList.length;

        }

    }

}
```

А создаёте диалог во фрагменте соответственно так:

```
new BottomSheetDialogView(getContext(), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    SettingsFragment news = new SettingsFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.frame_container, news)
                           .commit();
                }
            });
```

Comment: крошится ссылается на `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager(); ` открываю диалог из фрагмента и диалог должен вернуть нажатую позицию, вот это я хочу сделать. хотел через `PreferenceManager` обновлять фрагмент но не могу разобраться

Comment: ,А нет краш только если вызываю из `fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` А так все нормально, Как мне вызывать диалог при нажатии? И как закрыть его после нажатия чтобы он не стакался, и передать значение `mBoundString`.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `(StartActivity)context` в методе `SimpleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(*)` используйте `StartActivity.this` (следует из stack trace).

Comment: Не прокатит, у автора `SimpleAdapter` статичный, и не факт что вложен в класс `StartActivity`. Хотя если вложить в `StartActivity` и убрать `static`, то можно и так.

Comment: @NikolayNIK , помоги пож. я вызываю из фрагмента этот диалог и хочу получить обратно значение